# What is translation for 或作譈懟，亦書作憞 ?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, literary-chinese

In the sentence from the Kang-Xi Dictionary 或作譈懟，亦書作憞, I looked up
the characters 譈,懟,憞 all are pronounced  dui4 and all  are translated as to hate. I am confused  and do not know how to deal with this sentence. I am not sure, but those 3 charaters does not strike me as commonly used characters, or do they ?

Answer (score 1):

或作譈懟，亦書作憞 means "also, it is identified to 譈 or 懟; and it can be written as 憞."
They are all archaic words and no longer used today. Neither orally nor literally.

Comment: But even if they are no longer used, neither orally nor literally, would an average Chinese recognize its meaning if he saw them ?

Comment: No. They can't do that without the help of dictionary.
: ]

Answer (score 0):

康熙字典(KangXi Dictionary) is a rarely used dictionary, you can't even find it in a common book store in China. You should go to special book stores or big library to find one if you need it. 
So, it's not a dictionary for ordinary people, most of characters it contains are no longer used in nowadays. My suggestion is you should not dig so deep if you are just begin to learn Chinese.